# How to cement two xpath expressions into one?

Tags: xpath

Can't get any idea to cement the two expressions into one xpath. They both fall under the same class "pagination". I need to use that in a loop. I tried separately like this:

```
//div[@class='pagination']//a/@href
//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(@class,'next')]/@href
```

Elements for the expression:

```
<div class="pagination"><p><span>Showing</span>1-30
of 483<span>results</span></p><ul><li><span class="disabled">1</span></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&amp;page=2" data-page="2" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:2}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">2</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&amp;page=3" data-page="3" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:3}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">3</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&amp;page=4" data-page="4" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:4}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">4</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&amp;page=5" data-page="5" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132,&quot;module&quot;:1,&quot;listing_page&quot;:5}" data-remote="true" data-impressed="1">5</a></li><li><a href="/search?search_terms=pizza&amp;geo_location_terms=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&amp;page=2" data-page="2" data-analytics="{&quot;click_id&quot;:132}" data-remote="true" class="next ajax-page" data-impressed="1">Next</a></li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can combine two XPath expressions. One way, for example, is to use the union operator "|". Whether that's the right operator to use depends on what you want to achieve. Unfortunately you forget to tell us what you want to achieve, so that might not be the right operator for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks sir Michael Kay, for your response. I wanted to write xpath 
in such a way so that it covers both category of pagination. The opposite of what i want is:
"//div[@class='pagination']//a[not(@class)]/@href"

Comment: Did you mean to say this? Well, it works but I wanted to have the expressions combined in such a way so that it looks concise. [//div[@class='pagination']//a/@href|//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(@class,'ajax-page')]/@href]

Comment: You've got a path expression that returns X, and another path expression that returns Y. What do you want the combined path expression to return? The union operator will return all nodes selected by either X or Y. Alternatives are the "intersect" operator which returns everything selected by both X and Y, the "comma" (concatenation) operator which is similar to union but doesn't eliminate duplicates, etc... Without knowing what you want to achieve, we can't tell you what operator to use.

Comment: If union is the right operator for what you want to achieve, then "|" distributes through "/", so `(A/B/C | A/B/D)` can be replaced by `(A/B/(C|D))`. But that's legal only in XPath 2.0. In XPath 1.0 you can rewrite it in some cases as `(A/B/*[self::C or self::D])`. But in your example the nodes selected by the second expression are a subset of those selected by the first expression, so I really don't know what you want.

Comment: Your second answer on this is what i expect. I tried sir Kay with comma but it shows invalid expression. Perhaps, i can't put the comma in between in the right way

Comment: I tried like this: "//div[@class='pagination']//a[contains(concat(' ', @cla‌​ss, ' '), ' next ')]/@hr‌​ef"

Comment: You still haven't said what you are trying to achieve, or which XPath version you are using. The comma operator requires XPath 2.0.

Comment: I've already got it working-the one immediately before your latest comment. Thanks sir.